# Why does my html and css website always put my buttons in the wrong place

Tags: html, css

im making a website from scratch for the first time, i am formally educated on html but not css
pls explain heres my html

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <title>Jinuine Design | Home</title>
</head>
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="imgs/JinuineFavicon.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="home">
        <a href="index.html" class="homelink">
            <h1 class="homebutt">Home</h1>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

heres my css

```
.header {
height: 100px;
background: black;
}
.homebutt {
    color: black;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 110px;
}
```

someone please explain how to get the effect i want this is what it looks like
[ss of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl03v.jpg)

Comment: What is the "effect you want"? there is no question here...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the style to `.logo`, not `.header`

```css
.logo {
height: 100px;
background: black;
}
.homebutt {
    color: black;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 110px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <title>Jinuine Design | Home</title>
</head>
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="imgs/JinuineFavicon.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="home">
        <a href="index.html" class="homelink">
            <h1 class="homebutt">Home</h1>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Well IDK if that's really the problem the headers just the black background

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl03v.jpg
here background is black

Comment: originally, you set the style that has the fixed height of 100px to the `.header`, but this header container has also the Home div container, so you shoud set the 100px style to the logo container only

Answer (score 0):

Please remove padding on button.

> The CSS padding properties are used to generate space around an element's content, inside of any defined borders.
> With CSS, you have full control over the padding. There are properties
> for setting the padding for each side of an element (top, right,
> bottom, and left).